# Codeless IAP unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Android was not restoring non-consumable item so I add the IAP listener now it's restoring my non-consumable item but now when I buy consumable item it gives me double like I bought 50 gold but it gives me 100 gold I think it's happening because of Im using the same script for IAP listener but I don't know what im gonna code for IAP listener Im gonna put some image and my script so you can understand more clearly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERV9r.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVtXc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD8WO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ8Rk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqLj.png

```
    public void OnPurchaseCompleted(Product product)
{
    if(product != null)
    {
        switch (product.definition.id)
        {
            case "go50.ld":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 50);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[3] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "gold.100":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 100);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[3] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "gold.250":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 250);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[3] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "gold.500":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 500);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[3] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "gold.1000":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Gold", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold") + 1000);
                GoldText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold").ToString();
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[3] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Gold");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                Debug.Log("Completed");
                break;
            case "remove.ads":
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Remove", 1);
                Destroy(AdManager.Instance.gameObject);
                CloudVariables.ImportantValues[5] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Remove");
                PlayGamesController.Instance.SaveCloud();
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Failed");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Unity Console it seems that you are firing the event twice, check where you are calling that event. Also in the IAPButton screenshot the gold you have selected is 100, not 50, maybe that's the issue.